# Step a motor from a slow charging power source

Tags: motor, flipflop, low-power

I'd like to design a circuit that can power a stepper motor from a very weak power source such as a solar cel. Physics will of course make that a problem, but in my case I have no need to power the motor quickly, or at a consistent step rate - even just one step per 1-2 hours would be enough, so I'm hoping there is way to do this.

My general thought was something like this:

- Use a step-up converter to convert the low voltage from the solar cel to something higher with lower current
- Use the stepped up voltage to charge a capacitor
- When the capacitor reaches a sufficient voltage disconnect the solar cel and use the stored energy in the capacitor to power a microcontroller & stepper motor for long enough to make one step cw/ccw based on some logic in the MC
- store the current step phase in the microcontroller's persistent memory
- disconnect the motor and microcontroller and wait for the capacitor to reach the voltage threshold again

My question is whether this logic would really work? And whether it's possible to do in a closed loop way that doesn't rely in an external element checking whether the charge is high enough to trigger the motor step?

I'm very early on in my electronics learning but to me this looks like a behaviour that could possibly be achieved with a flip flop that's used to alternate the power between charging/discharging the capacitor. But, my understanding is still loose enough that I'm not sure if my understanding is wrong, or simply my attempts at implementation.

Also as a side note. I've chosen a stepper motor in the use case as it has a fairly strong passive holding torque. A DC motor would definitely be simpler to control, and possibly remove the need for storing state in the microcontroller memory, but wold be less stable when the motor was unpowered.

---

### Edit

Here's my attempt at a version that's using a DC motor. In theory, when a bank of capacitors charge reaches a potential of 15v, then turn off when it drops back down below 5v.

[image: Circuit Attempt]

It's not functioning currently, I think that's down to the SR latch, but I'm at the edge of my understanding and having a hard time diagnosing.

The 20V power supply is coming from a step up converter attached to a solar cel. The 50K resistor is there to slow down the capacitors charging speed in simulation.

Comment: Depending on your actual motor load you may need a rather large capacitor bank, or batteries as an alternative.  Do you actually need accurate steps even though it doesn't matter when/how frequently they happen?

Comment: The load will be minimal, barely more than the motor spindle itself on something like a miniature DVD drive motor. I don't need accurate steps at all, I mainly thought stepper motor because of the holding torque, with a relatively high number of zero power discreet positions. I'm very open to other types of motor or power storage.

Comment: A motor is rarely a minimal load by capacitor standards, so even with a motor you think is small you might need quite a large capacitor bank to ensure the voltage doesn't drop too much while you perform a step.  Running a microcontroller in extremely low power modes can be very challenging.  I'm not sure what you mean by not using external elements, but you need something to wake up the microcontroller when the capacitor is adequately charged.  If you're using solar power, it's worth noting that Maximum Power Point Tracking(MPPT) circuits are used when maximizing output is critical.

Comment: By not using external elements, I really mean that I'd like the circuit to be able to charge up and switch on on its own, without myself, or a separate powered circuit stepping in to make that switch.Thanks for the pointer on MPPT circuits, I'll go read up. Also, thanks for taking the time to help out!

Comment: Rechargeable battery will be better solution. Voltage of capacitor depends on amount of electricity and may vary. Also consider battery and capacitor in parallel due to motor start current.

Comment: At any rate, it might be worth considering using a different type of motor than a stepper, like a DC motor with a gearbox and a much simpler control system like a few comparators and gates.  You could probably get decent but inaccurate bursts of rotation with just a reasonable sized capacitor bank that way.  Your logic would be pretty simple and low power without a sleep state: If voltage>start threshold, latch motor ON:  If voltage<stop threshold, open latch.

Comment: @KH that sounds like the correct solution to me. Do you have any insights as to how to achieve the latching? or what search terms to use to find out? Some kind of flip flop setup seems right to me, but my intuition is not that sharp yet.

Comment: I'd write an answer but I've got to go for now.  If you want to start learning the parts you need, look up voltage divider, comparator, SR latch, MOSFET driver, MOSFET.

Comment: This all sounds a lot like Solarbotics and their BEAM project. http://solarbotics.net/ with all the critters they built http://solarbotics.net/bestiary/default.htm and now supported by a business https://solarbotics.com/ (which may offer suitable components)

Comment: Very low-power stepper techniques are used in common quartz-crystal battery-driven wrist watches. You might look at their methods, particularly how the solenoid is driven efficiently.

Comment: @BrianDrummond thanks for the link!

Comment: @glen_geek thats totally fascinating! I had no idea that's how it worked, thanks for the insight!

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to study up on how stepper motors work. Rather than using an SR gate, you'll need to use a stepper motor driver. For your purposes you may find it easier to use a unipolar rather than a bipolar motor, so you'll need to drive 4 different motor phases (the stepper driver IC will take care of this). The whole thing will wind up being rather more complicated than your present approach.